# Do idol worshippers don't get moksha or is this statement symbolic(not literal)?

Tags: moksha, idols

***Maitrey upnishad chapter 2 verse 26***

> To one desiring liberation worship of idols made of stone, metal, gem
> and clay results only in the experience of rebirth; hence the sage
> should perform the worship of his heart alone (i.e. contemplate on
> Brahman enshrined in his heart, non-different from the Self). To
> prevent rebirth he shall avoid external worship (of idols).

*I want to know does this verse mean anything symbolically (like clear internal badness and connect to brahman) or is it literal verse like one who desire of moksha must stop worshipping idols??*

If I want moksha should I stop worshipping idols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idol worship isn't related to Moksha. It doesn't affect it positively nor negatively.

The upanishat is simply saying that IF you really want Moksha, then your time is better spent in doing practices that are directly related to Moksha (Dhyaana, giving up attachment etc) rather than spending it on something that is mostly unrelated to Moksha.

If you worship idols, then you will still get Moksha, it's just a little less likely as you're putting a part of your mental resources in another place.

Also, there's a encouragement here to give up desire to material things, as 'idol worship' or, worship of Devas in general, via Yajnas primarily, is associated with you wanting material things (like money, fame etc). The text is telling you to give up desire for material/worldly objects and engage in desire for Moksha.

Moreover, if you check the actual Sanskrit, what is translated as "sage" is यति which essentially means a Sannyaasi for most purposes. So, giving up outward attachments is definitely what is implied by worshiping of outside entities.

Also, keep in mind that the text doesn't say idol anywhere at the end, the translator has just put it in based on his own mind (in brackets) based on the earlier context. It applies to everything that is focused on the material world, not just idols (which makes sense since it's for Sannyaasis). Texts like these usually have double or triple layers of meanings.

Comment: Is there any verse where idol worship is promoted (for those who want moksha) from upnishads?Asking out of curiosity

Comment: @Hope sure, it's mentioned in passing in the Ganapatyatharvashirsham upanishat. सूर्यग्रहेमहानद्यां प्रतिमासन्निधौ वा जप्त्वा सिद्धमन्त्रो भवति -  He who recites this during Solar Eclipse on the bank of a great River, or in-front of the **form** of Ganapati, becomes Mantra-Siddha.

You will naturally not find these sorts of mentions in Upanishats for Sannyaasis though (of which, Matreya Upanisat is one).

Comment: Or more clearly, from the same Upanishat: अनेन गणपतिमभिषिञ्चति स वाग्मी भवति ।
चतुर्थ्यामनश्नन् जपति स विद्यावान् भवति ।
इत्यथर्वणवाक्यम् ।
ब्रह्माद्यावरणं विद्यान्न बिभेति कदाचनेति ॥१५॥ 
15.1: He who anoints Ganapati with this Upanishad becomes a fluent Speaker (Vagmi),
He who fasts on Chaturthi and recites this Upanishad becomes filled with Knowledge (becomes Vidyavan),
This is the word of the Atharvana Rishi,
He (finally) gains the Knowledge of the envelop of Brahman (aka Moksha), and thereafter does not have any fear anytime.